# Addind single object to DbContext implicitly produces infinite new objects

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a huge EF model. At some step I add multiple different objects into the context and call SaveChanges() like this:

```
ctx.DbSet1.Add(obj1);
ctx.DbSet2.Add(obj2); // magic line
ctx.DbSet3.Add(obj3);
....
ctx.DbSet100.Add(obj100);
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

I notices that *sometimes* this code throws exception with message:

> Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations.
>   Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints, model
>   requirements, or store-generated values.

Because there were really many objects then I had to find the exact line producing error. So I ended up with this code:

```
ctx.DbSet1.Add(obj1);
ctx.SaveChanges(); // works well
ctx.DbSet2.Add(obj2); // magic line
ctx.SaveChanges(); // getting error here
ctx.DbSet3.Add(obj3);
```

I found that SaveChanged executed exactly after object #2 *simetimes* produces this error. I run application many times in the same way and it *sometimes* worked well, other times the magic line added hundreds of entities to context with State = Added. The object 2 is not self-referencing, but by the Context schema yes, there is a cycle reference throw maybe ten tables.
I am not asking to solve the issue, but please, what are *possible* reasons for context creates many objects after one object has been added?
Thank you!

Comment: There's no way to answer this without seeing your data model.

Comment: Can convert to this: what are possible reasons for context creates many objects after one object has been added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that object #2 was not created as new but declared as *static* instead (by the business logic in our system we have a number of predefined objects). So #2 kept its properties and related parents and collections (all those objects #1, #3, ..., #100) once for all.

On each round-trip, thinking of object #2 as of a brand new one, we gave its foreign keys new values and this affected all bunch of related entities and this seemed to produce the race which created tons of entities.